# TypeOrm: Selecting results that contain all values in array

Tags: javascript, sql, query-builder, typeorm

I am having some trouble getting the data I want from a Typeorm query.

Basically, we have a search bar for the users to search our database of products (medicines). I want to select all records from the database that include every word the user entered. (These words are split into an array of values.) It might not be a perfect match for the product name, so I'm thinking I should use `LIKE`?

We have English, Japanese, and Chinese results in the database. I want to search the English name (nameEn), Japanese name (nameJa), and Chinese name (nameZh) for any results that contain all the user's search queries.

I'm unsure how I can programmatically loop over the search queries as well as building the query for Typeorm at the same time.

Current code:

```js
const medicines = await getRepository(Medicine)
  .createQueryBuilder('medicine')
  .where('medicine.nameEn like :query', { query: '%bufferin%' })
  .andWhere(
    new Brackets((qb) => {
      qb.where('medicine.nameEn like :query1', {
        query1: '%luna%',
      }).orWhere('medicine.nameEn like :query2', { query2: 'EX' });
    }),
  )
  .getMany();
```

This works for getting English products that match... but right now I've just hard coded in the query "bufferin luna EX". How would I do this if it was `['bufferin', 'luna', 'EX']`, and also wanted to check `nameJa` and `nameZh`?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing it a bit more, I managed to come up with a way to do this dynamically by saving an instance of the Select Query Builder, then adding `.andWhere` chains for each query. Posting the code in case it helps anyone in the future.

```
// get instance of Select Query Builder
let builder = await getRepository(Items)
  .createQueryBuilder('item')

// validating data
  .where('item.categoryId is not null')
  .andWhere('item.companyId is not null');
    

queries.map((query, index) => {
  const queryName = `query_${index}`;
  const escapedQuery = escapeLikeString(query);

  builder = builder   
  .andWhere(`item.nameEn like :${queryName}`, { [queryName]: `%${escapedQuery}%` })
  .orWhere(`item.nameJa like :${queryName}`, { [queryName]: `%${escapedQuery}%` })
  .orWhere(`item.nameZh like :${queryName}`, { [queryName]: `%${escapedQuery}%` })
});
    
  const items = await builder.getMany();
```